# RStudio notebook does not show data.frames when I compile

Tags: r, rstudio, rnotebook

I have a temporary windows 7 laptop (32 bit) on which I have R 3.3.2 and RStudio 1.0.44.

I am using RStudio notebook, and it works fine when I execute code in its window. However, as I compile to html (pressing Preview), the data.frames disappear (there is a chunk with no output). Everything else (vectors or figures) are shown.
It seems to be linked to the new cute printing format for data.frames that the notebook exploits. Indeed, if I use R-markdown (switching to `output: html_document`), the data.frames are shown with no problem in the basic R format.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It looks like this is a problem specifically with rmarkdown 1.2 and RStudio v1.0.44. I believe the issue should be resolved with RStudio v1.0.132; if you want to try installing it you can find it at http://dailies.rstudio.com -- hopefully a patch release will be available that fixes this up soon!

Comment: Ok thanks for your help. If the problem is with the RStudio version, I can also resort to some previous versions, because everything worked fine up to 10 days ago when I built the HTML file. Today I discovered the problem after re-compiling the Rmd on a new laptop with the newest version of RStudio.

Comment: Another resolution is to install the development version of rmarkdown, with e.g. `devtools::install_github("rstudio/rmarkdown")`.

Comment: @Kevin Ushey Yes I solved installing rmarkdown 1.1 using devtools. Another little problem I noticed with rmarkdown 1.2 is the bad extra space added between the text and the following chunk. It made the HTML file quite unreadable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the ones having this problem, it turned out the issue was related to `rmarkdown 1.2`.
I solved installing `rmarkdown 1.1`:

```
remove.packages("rmarkdown")
library(devtools)
install_version("rmarkdown", version = "1.1", 
                repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Then everything worked.